# GET /accounts list returns an empty list for my sandbox merchant (UCP)

Tags: global-payments-api

I am attempting to retrieve details about the accounts of my sandbox merchant account using the API `https://developer.globalpay.com/api/accounts` but I keep receiving an empty list.

I have tried using the `filter` of the query as per the example on the page above to no avail. I have also tried leaving the query parameter list empty, still no luck.

Funny thing, I have tried using the embedded function "Run Test" on the page listed above and now it also now returns an empty list !  It seems this API end-point is touchy... I have tried a query using `from_time_created` set 1971-01-01 and I got a Gateway Timeout (504) errors for quite a while.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

UPDATED: I just registered a new sandbox account. I created the required default application. I tried using the same API through https://developer.globalpay.com/api/accounts and again the API returns an empty list. Something is broken on the side of Global Payments...